# Ubuntu Desktop Sharing History

Tags: remote

Hello is there any way to view the history of all the remote connections made by the built-in application called **Desktop Sharing** ?

i would like to make sure myself that there was not connection made between me and anyone else.

Comment: Do you want a record of incoming or outgoing connections?

Comment: yes basicaly i have never connected anywhere but i just want to know whether there was not connection to me using that destkop sharing application in ubuntu

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Did you ever enable the desktop sharing option?

Comment: i was testing that option and since im newbie im not sure if i didnot screw something so thats why im looking for this log just to make sure nothing bad happend.

Comment: shouldnot sudo last show whether someone connected to the machine ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the default Ubuntu VNC server `vino`, incredibly there is no log information produced by this application, so there is no straightforward way to see who connected to it.

There has been a [bug/feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/330310) regarding this for years.

Comment: i dont run any server i just installed ubuntu on my notebook and i want to know if someone has ever connected to me using that app

Comment: If you don't run a vnc server on your computer then no one can connect to your computer using vnc.  But, just so you know, what you are doing when you enable "desktop sharing" is starting a vnc server.  People who connect to it use vnc client applications such as remmina.  So I think you are running a server, you just don't recognize that fact.  If you don't want to do that, disable remote desktop.

Comment: it is already disabled and i havenot installed any server packages so it means the server is built in and whenever you check the box , allow users to view destkop it starts the server ? thanks but , still , does that destkop sharing client log incomming connections or no ?

Comment: if i havenot installed vnc server then it means even if i activate the  destkop sharing , noone can connect to me ? i have to manualy install vnc via terminal?

Comment: As I said in the answer "incredibly there is no log information produced by this application, so there is no straightforward way to see who connected to it."

Comment: ok i got it thanks but what about the last comment i wrote